# Phpmyadmin hangs when i click on table structure

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, ampps

Please tell what may be reason when I click on structure tab on right frame of a table, it hangs for at least 10 seconds and then the screen adjusts itself with table structure details.

Comment: Give us more information, such as PMA version, browser version, server setup, etc.

Comment: try adding the screenshots are screenshot links to help us know your table structure.

Comment: There are only 10 fields. The same details on remote server doesn't hang but on local server it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on many factors.

- Whether you are accessing database on localhost or remote host.
- Your browser and internet speed.
- Shared or dedicated hosting.

If you are on shared hosting and accessing using phpmyadmin then this things happens.
Try using [adminer.php](https://www.adminer.org/static/download/4.2.2/adminer-4.2.2.php)

Comment: It's not a remove host. It doesn't require internet. It is localhost and I am using Ampps local server.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons:

Your server's memory is being used up.

You have a large table structure.

You have a slow internet connection.

Try using another computer, speak to your server provider and ask them if there is any memory issues with the server where your services are hosted.

Comment: It's not about internet or table structure as there are only 10 fields and I am using AMPPS local server. Memory allocation could be the issue which may be adjusted using php.ini. But according to me the reason may be the screen adjustment. I am using screen resolution of 1366x768.